# python pickle not consistent

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pickle, xgboost

I'm using python3.5 on Ubuntu. I trained a model by xgboost sklearn wrapper and save it by pickle.

Here is a link of the pickle file:
https://pan.baidu.com/s/1eSoPWxs

The question is each time I load it, the result is different.

For example:

```
a = pickle.load(open('mymodel', 'rb'))

b = pickle.load(open('mymodel', 'rb'))

print(a == b)
```

I got result `False`, but I think it should be `True`.

Can anybody explain this? Is there any way to solve this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not familiar with xgboost, but what is the class of `a` and `b`? What does its `__eq__` method do? If no `__eq__` is defined, it defaults to `a is b` which is obviously `False` in your case.

Comment: Can you `print a` and `print b` after each call and show the output?

Answer (score 1):

When sklearn is not installed, the base class of the `XGBoostModel` is the same as `object`:

[`XGBModelBase = object`](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/python-package/xgboost/compat.py#L68)

And you probably already know that two instances of `object` are not equal:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> pickle.dump(object(), open('test.txt', 'wb'))
>>> a = pickle.load(open('test.txt', 'rb'))
>>> b = pickle.load(open('test.txt', 'rb'))
>>> a == b
False
```

---

```
>>> object() == object()
False
```

I'll expect the behavior of `__eq__` on the base class `XGBModelBase` to be consistent in the case sklearn is installed.

Also note that `__eq__` was not overriden in the model class, so the behavior you have is as expected.

You may try comparing the dictionaries of the unpickled models and see if that works for you: `a.__dict__ == b.__dict__`

Comment: Thanks for your answers! @Moses, sorry about not knowing that the two instances of an object are not equal. What I really care about is that every time I load the model by pickle and predict on the same validation set, I get different results. However, after loading the model, no matter how many times running the prediction, the same result is gotten. So I guess if there is something unpicklable in the model? Since xgboost model is a bunch of parameters, which is quite complex, it may contain something unpicklable, which causes the difference between every time of its loading. Is there any way

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem, which is nothing to do with pickle. There is something else which causes some randomization in each running.

Thanks for help! Sorry for bothering!

Ben